# Server mode SSL startHandshake on Android took 12 seconds to finish

Tags: android, ssl

I am new to Android. For an application, I need to upgrade a plain TCP socket to SSL socket (server mode) on Android. The following code worked, but it took about 12 seconds to finish the SSL handshake on Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.3.3 (API 10). I also tested the same code on simulator with android 4.0.3 (API 15), the result was same. The client was Chrome browser. From the Wireshark trace, all the SSL handshake messages flowed very fast, and then there was a 10 seconds gap between the Change Cipher Spec/Encrypted Handshake message (last two messages of SSL handshake on server side) and the first application Data (it was HTTP GET from chrome).

```
private boolean handleSSLHandshake() {

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(this.kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        SSLSocketFactory factory = sc.getSocketFactory();            
        this.sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(this.socket,
                                         this.socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(),
                                         this.socket.getPort(),
                                         true);
        this.sslSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
        this.sslSocket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(this);
        this.sslSocket.startHandshake();
        Log.d(TAG, "SSL upgrade succeeds!");
        this.input = this.sslSocket.getInputStream();
        this.output = this.sslSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got NoSuchAlgorithmException while upgrading to SSL" + e);
        this.sslSocket = null;
        return false;
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got KeyManagementException while upgrading to SSL" + e);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got UnknownHostException while upgrading to SSL" + e);
        this.sslSocket = null;
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got IOException while upgrading to SSL" + e);
        this.sslSocket = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent event) {

    Log.d(TAG, "SSL handshake completed");
}
```

Does anyone have clue on which code took 10 seconds? How to reduce this? And how to debug the SSL handshake on Android?

Thanks a lot for help,

/Kaiduan

Comment: Why are you setting clientMode to false? Is the server set to clientMode=true? This is not the default, and it is very rare to change it.

Comment: SSL server handshakes definitely shouldn't take that long. The Android test cases include running SSL servers and that doesn't take very long. Where are you getting the certificate? That might be what's taking 10 seconds; cert generation tends to take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor load on the device to see if the CPU is busy during those 10 secs. Also try on different devices and/or the emulator to see if you get the same results. Another possibility is that it's waiting on DNS, but that shouldn't happen that late. Check your packet captures for DNS queries.